# Wordpress Mixed content

Tags: wordpress, ssl

I am having a very weird issue. I am working on my new site and there are three images that are coming up as mixed content. The issue is I cannot for the life of me find the images in the html sources, or in the database. If anyone could help I would appercaite it.

Here is the site [website with error](https://www.webking.com/seo2)

Here is the error I am getting.

> (index):1 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://example.com/seo2/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image 'http://example.com/seo2/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/wave.png'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.
>   (index):1 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://example.com/seo2/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image 'http://example.com/seo2/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/work_process.png'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.
>   (index):1 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://example.com/seo2/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image 'http://example.com/seo2/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/testimonialbg1.jpg'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution hiding in a css file.

Thanks for everyones time